# C++ restbed framework using vcpkg

Tags: c++, restbed

I have written an API in C++ and restbed framework. I have installed restbed using vcpkg in my debian machine. When I issue the command **vcpkg list** , restbed is displayed . However, when I include it in my header-file and try to compile , the build fails with

**fatal error: 'restbed' file not found [build] #include restbed**

Since I am working with VSCode, inside a header-file where I have restbed included, if I right click on it to peek **Go To Definition**, a restbedC++ file with more files inside of it like this opens up:

```
#include "corvusoft/restbed/uri.hpp"
#include "corvusoft/restbed/http.hpp"
#include "corvusoft/restbed/rule.hpp"
#include "corvusoft/restbed/byte.hpp"
```

Which gives me the impression that restbed is installed but I must be missing something.

I am unfamiliar with C++, especially for WebDev. Any help, suggestions and clarifications will highly be appreciated. Thanks.

CMakeLists.txt looks like :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(API)

add_executable(API 
    main.cpp
    CalcResourceFactory.cpp
    CalcService.cpp
    CalcServiceSettingsFactory.cpp)

file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp")
target_link_libraries(API /home/kali/Applications/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include/restbed)
target_include_directories(API PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
set_property(TARGET API PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/kali/Applications/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)
```

While my properties json file looks like:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath":[
                "${workspaceFolder}/projectC++Server**",
                "/home/kali/Applications/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include",
                "projectC++Server/include",
                "projectC++Server"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles. I have added the files above .

Comment: I've not used vcpkg but I don't think you have setup your cmake file correctly https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/installing-and-using-packages/#step-2-use, I'd be surprised if setting `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` inside the cmakefile will work

Answer (score 0):

`vcpkg` requires an install phase, which you have completed and an `integrate` phase, during which the linker paths and header paths are added to the VS IDE.

See here - https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started.html

If you have done `vcpkg integrate install` and it still does not recognize the paths - you will need to add the header search path using `-I` and the linker paths using `-L` to your project settings.

Comment: I have done integrate install. Please if you may , can you elaborate a little on "you will need to add the header search path using -I and the linker paths using -L to your project settings."

Comment: See here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference - modify `includePath` to ensure the rested folder is included. Or include files with the full path, so in your C++ file use - `#include "corvusoft/restbed/uri.hpp"` etc. You have to include all the .hpp files needed by your C++ program.

Comment: This is the wrong way to include headers in C++ `#include restbed` - it may be just a syntax issue.